# Can azure webjob run simultaneously?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I currently have a webjob that runs when user does specific action. 
When the webjob is running it cannot accept a new request until its done with the current process. 
Is it possible to run webjob simultaneously, meaning be able to process a job for multiple clients at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. But how are you triggering your WebJob when a user performs a specific action? If you trigger a method within your WebJob via a QueueTrigger that listens for a message on an Azure Storage Queue, you can have multiple threads processing messages at once. You can do something similar using Service Bus queues as well.

Check out the docs in the [parallel execution section here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to#a-idblobsa-how-to-read-and-write-blobs-and-tables-while-processing-a-queue-message).

Comment: Im currently triggerring it via web job REST api/post call, im assuming that will not be a proper way of doing it right?

Comment: That is one way to do it. There are other benefits of using queues though, such as the ability to lease a message and mark it as complete when you have successfully finished processing (for Storage queues), or accomplishing the same thing with a PeekLock receive mode for Service Bus queues. That way, if your webjob method errors out or crashes during processing, you can attempt to process again. If you did this with a RESTful web service call and a crash occurs, you are *@&# out of luck.

Comment: Another benefit of using queues to communicate is that if your webjob goes down temporarily (for maintenance or due to a crash), messages will accumulate in your queue and will be processed when the webjob comes back online. This is called temporal decoupling. One more: if your web app gets slammed and tries to make a bunch of web service calls to a computationally intensive webjob process, you can swamp the webjob. With a message queue, work just backs up in the queue and is processed when the webjob catches up. This builds elasticity to handle spikes in your application.

Comment: I think i found my answer. Im going to look into queues and be back if i run into more issues. Thank you!!!!

Comment: just for a FYI or if someone else is interested, Can you explain how it would be possible to run multiple instances simultaneously using rest api/post call?

Comment: Honestly, I thought you should see parallelism if you are treating methods marked as [NoAutomaticTrigger] as web service endpoints. What are you seeing when you make back to back calls?

Comment: "409 CONFLICT
The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource. This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request."

Comment: I am almost certain that this isn't a limitation of being able to call WebJob methods simultaneously. I'd look for any resources that are being shared between concurrent executions. Or maybe you've got some residual corrupted lock files in your Blob storage account? You could try deleting them and seeing if the problem resolves. They will live in the Blob portion of your Storage account designated by AzureWebJobsStorage in your app.config (or hosting Web App Settings section). Those are just guesses without having seen your code.

Comment: Hmm, none of those are related. My webjob consists of .exe that processes some text (read from a file) and outputs some processed text. No blob storage or shared resources. The .exe does have "resources" (files) that it uses that is stored within same folder as .exe. Is that considered as shared resource?

Comment: Absolutely. If multiple threads in your webjob are all trying to acquire a write lock on a text file, you will very likely get contention. Only one write lock can be held on a file at a time.